# MonoDevelop-bin package required (Arch Linux)

Tags: c#, ide, monodevelop, archlinux

MonoDevelop was completly removed from AUR. So now I have no access to any version of this IDE! I tryed to search in packman pkg cage but found nothing! I need this version: monodevelop-bin-7.8.4.1_0xamarin6_ubuntu1804b1-2 or higher. If anyone have information where I can fond package or pkgbuild file, please give it to me. This is the only one IDE I can use normaly (I have VS Code, but it quite uncomfortable to use for me). Thanks for you attention and PLEASE HELP if you can. If you have any other versions of monodevelop for arch linux, please give me a link.

Comment: I found that https://archive.org/download/archlinux_pkg_monodevelop . But all of them are lover than 7.8.4.1 that I use now.

Comment: [Relevant](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=267529)

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-end-of-monodevelop-80b383dab34b What you want is not likely to happen.

Comment: Lex Li. MonoDevelop is no longer supported, I know, but I need to say that this IDE is still the BEST FREE IDE for C# for Linux OS. For Rider you need to pay, VS Code is VS Code, Atom is not very far from VS Code... So MonoDevelop is still the best IDE. Visual Studio 2019 analogue for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!!!
https://github.com/williamd1k0/monodevelop-bin - the version I searched for (monodevelop-bin-7.8.4.1_0xamarin6_ubuntu1804b1-2) Thanks to William Tumeo.

https://github.com/orgs/aur-archive/repositories?q=monodevelop&type=all&language=&sort= - A lot of other MonoDevelop versions.

https://archive.org/download/archlinux_pkg_monodevelop - old MonoDevelop versions arcive.

I think I will create MonoDevelop ArchLinux versions archive on my git.